# Custom segue to specific sub-view in navigation controller hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a Sign Up wizard flow in a storyboard, it's a Navigation Controller (as the storyboard entry point) with ordinary Back/Next buttons in the navbar and then 4 sub-step Scenes with Show/Push segue transitions in a linear chain.

Normally I custom segue to the storyboard's navigation controller and the wizard then starts at the first step and everything's fine.

But from another point in the app I need to modally go to one of the sub-steps (not the first), and I don't want to copy/paste the entire view and the class controlling it into a whole new navigation controller chain, so I figured I could segue directly to it (and dynamically adjust what happens in the Back/Next buttons).

So I tried subclassing UIStoryboardSegue to do a custom segue for this, its sceneNamed method does something like this:

return [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:sceneName];

and it works, but since we instantiate the sub-scene's View Controller and not the Navigation Controller, I see the scene but don't get the navbar..

On the other hand if I segue to the Navigation Controller it starts at the first linked Scene as usual.

Is there any way to fool UIKit into going to the Navigation Controller but getting it to start at a scene further down the normal hierarchy/flow ?

Yes I realize this is hackish; there are other solutions (I can programmatically add Back/Next buttons for example in this case). Just curious.

Comment: You say "adjust the back/next buttons". This implies that the arrangement should not be the same as when you push push push to reach this scene originally. Can you say more about the arrangement now _should_ be?

Comment: @matt So, the sub-view I want to re-use is a Terms of Service Accept view, it's normally in the Sign Up flow, but I want to issue it modally from the Login view if the user hasn't accepted the latest ToS. So, in the Sign Up flow, the Back/Next buttons act "normally" and have Interface Builder associated segues, but when used in the Login modal way, I figured I'd hook their actions to be "Decline" and "Accept" instead and handle the transitions manually. I agree this seems more and more stupid to mix programmatic stuff with the Storyboard stuff...

Comment: So what you want is just a navigation controller containing only this one ToS view? So why not just configure that in the storyboard? Another navigation controller, with its root view controller being this same ToS controller (no need to "copy" anything).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So why not hook up the segues like this:

```
Navigation Controller (sign up) ->
  VC1 -> VC2 -> Terms of Service -> VC3
                       ↑
Login View ->          |                          
     Navigation Controller
```

This way, you simply have two different ways of reaching Terms of Service view controller, with no need to copy it. You can use a Storyboard Reference object to configure this without having a bunch of criss-crossing arrows marring the storyboard.

Comment: True, I arrived at a similar conclusion after fiddling around with it a bit more - initially I missed that my Login View did in fact already have a navigation controller, it just had a hidden navigation bar. So by un-hiding it and seguing to the ToS page, I get the ToS page with navbar items (from the Login View nav controller).